# Match Similarity inside array in PHP

Tags: php, json, match

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "category_id": 13732,
      "name": "Artificial Fruits & Vegetables",
      "category_tree": "Home, Garden & Pets > Home Furnishings & Decor > Artificial Plants & Flowers",
      "google_category": {
        "id": 6265,
        "tree": "Home & Garden > Decor > Artificial Flora",
        "name": "Artificial Flora",
        "level": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "category_id": 13981,
      "name": "Vegetables",
      "category_tree": "Home, Garden & Pets > Garden & Outdoor Living > Plants, Seeds & Bulbs > Outdoor Plants",
      "google_category": {
        "id": 6762,
        "tree": "Home & Garden > Plants > Indoor & Outdoor Plants",
        "name": "Indoor & Outdoor Plants",
        "level": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "category_id": 17779,
      "name": "Vegetables",
      "category_tree": "Food & Drink > Food Cupboard > Tins, Cans & Jars",
      "google_category": {
        "id": 5798,
        "tree": "Food, Beverages & Tobacco > Food Items > Fruit & Vegetables > Canned & Jarred Vegetables",
        "name": "Canned & Jarred Vegetables",
        "level": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "category_id": 17800,
      "name": "Vegetables",
      "category_tree": "Food & Drink > Frozen Food",
      "google_category": {
        "id": 5793,
        "tree": "Food, Beverages & Tobacco > Food Items > Fruit & Vegetables > Fresh & Frozen Vegetables",
        "name": "Fresh & Frozen Vegetables",
        "level": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "category_id": 17806,
      "name": "Vegetables",
      "category_tree": "Food & Drink > Fruit & Veg",
      "google_category": {
        "id": 430,
        "tree": "Food, Beverages & Tobacco > Food Items > Fruit & Vegetables",
        "name": "Fruit & Vegetables",
        "level": 3
      }
    }
  ]
  }
```

I want to get the category which is most relevant/similar to this string

> "Ocado Own-Label/Fruit, Vegetables & Salad/Vegetables"

by matching through either category tree or name of each category object inside json.

please help, I'm new to PHP

...UPDATE...

```
<?php
similar_text("Beverages & Tobacco > Food Items > Fruit & Vegetables > Fresh & Frozen Vegetables","Ocado Own-Label/Fruit, Vegetables & Salad/Vegetables",$percent);
echo $percent;
?>
```

I want to search through using similar_text function and return the higest matching json object/category

Comment: Show us what you have tried, your best attempt(code). What does not work as expected? Do you get any error(s)? Suggested reading [ask].

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: So, do that in a loop then, and if the percentage for the current item is higher than your previous highest percentage, then the current item becomes your new “top candidate”.

Comment: what about first match? how will i compare it with previous match if there is nothing

Comment: For that you just need a special case in your logic for when the previous match is null - In that scenario the current item always becomes the "top" one (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

```
$decode = json_decode($json);
for($i=0; $i<count($decode->results); $i++){
    
    similar_text($decode->results[$i]->google_category->tree,"Ocado Own-Label/Fruit, Vegetables & Salad/Vegetables",$percent);
    $myarr[$i]=$percent;
}

$maxmatchcategory = array_search(max($myarr), $myarr);
echo $decode->results[$maxmatchcategory]->category_id.'<br>';
```